# ITunesConnect certificates required for testing and implementing in-app purchases

Tags: ios, testing, certificate, app-store-connect

I've been asked by my developer, who is currently developing IOS mobile apps, to provide him with a certificate and private key in order for him to implement in-app purchases and to test them on his device.

**Can you tell me what are the required certificates that he needs (Development certificate, Provision Certificates etc), and if he can do any harm with them (like publish the app himself etc)**.

I also have the option to add him as a test user in iTunes Connect, but he also stated that he needs the certificates in order to implement the in-app purchases, not only to test them.

Comment: study  developer.apple.com->member centre-> login there -> choose certificate, this is the section he has been asking about, it is up to you whether to give him your credentials, so that he can set all there by himself, or you can create one account there for him as well. but you need to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a development certificate.
You also need to create a test user and a test item int the In-App sandbox.

Take a look at the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html)